# Function parameter: Pointer to array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameters

In my main function I create an array of objects of a certain class "Menu"

And when I call a function I want to provide a pointer to that array.

```
Menu menu[2];
// Create menu [0], [1]
Function(POINTER_TO_ARRAY);
```

Question: What is the correct way to write the Function parameters?

I try:

```
Function(&menu);
```

and in Header file:

```
void Function(Menu *menu[]); // not working
error: Cannot convert parameter 1 from Menu(*)[2] to Menu *[]

void Function(Menu * menu); // not working
error: Cannot convert parameter 1 from Menu(*)[2] to Menu *[]
```

and I can't come up with any other way to do this and I can't find a solution to this particular problem.

Simply, I want to be able to access the Menu array within the function through a pointer. What are the difference in normal pointer to a pointer to an array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declaration:

```
void Function(Menu* a_menus); // Arrays decay to pointers.
```

Invocation:

```
Function(menu);
```

However, you would need to inform `Function()` how many entries are in the array. As this is C++ suggest using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which have knowledge of their size, beginning and end:

```
std::vector<Menu> menus;
menus.push_back(Menu("1"));
menus.push_back(Menu("2"));

Function(menus);

void Function(const std::vector<Menu>& a_menus)
{
    std::for_each(a_menus.begin(),
                  a_menus.end(),
                  [](const Menu& a_menu)
                  {
                      // Use a_menu
                  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Either by const or non-const pointer

```
void Function(Menu const* menu);
void Function(Menu* menu);
```

...or by const or non-const reference

```
void Function(Menu const (&menu)[2]);
void Function(Menu (&menu)[2]);
```

which can be generalized to a template so that the array size will be deduced by the compiler:

```
template<size_t N> void Function(Menu const (&menu)[N]);
template<size_t N> void Function(Menu (&menu)[N]);
```

Always call as `Function(menu);`

Answer (score 3):

Should work if you use

```
 void Function(Menu * menu);
```

and call using

```
Function(menu);
```

instead of

```
Function(&menu);
```

passing the array name causes it to decay to a pointer to the type contained in the array. However, as @hmjd says in his answer you will also need to pass the array size, so his suggestion of using a vector is favourable if this option is open to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Function((void *) whatever_pointer_type_or_array_of_classes);
```

in your main.

And in the function:

```
type Function(void * whatever)
{
    your_type * x =(your_type *) whatever;
    //use x 
    ....
    x->file_open=true;
    ....
}
```